How to use the output of a command as input of another command in fluentd?
With fluentd, I want to use each line of the output of jps -lv command (that lists the running JVM on machine), as input argument of jcmd <PID> GC.heap_info (that gives info on heap usage).
I've put a <source> with command jps -lv and run_interval 60 in order to cyclically launch jps, then a <match> of type @exec_filter with command gcmd process_pid GC.heap_info
Here are the contents of test.conf:
<source>
  @type exec
  tag m.jvm_insights.list
  command jps -lv
  run_interval 15
  # will return something like:
  # 12345 sun.tools.jps.Jps -lv
  # 12346 org.apache.flume.node.Application -Xmx20m -Xms20m -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
  <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /^(?<process_pid>\d+)\s+(?<process_name>.*)$/
    types process_pid:integer
    keys process_pid, process_name
  </parse>
</source>

<match m.jvm_insights.list>
  @type exec_filter
  tag m.jvm_insights.heap_info
  command jcmd $process_pid GC.head_info
  # Will output something like:
  # 12346:
  #  garbage-first heap   total 258048K, used 4967K [0x0000000708c00000, 0x0000000800000000)
  #   region size 2048K, 2 young (4096K), 0 survivors (0K)
  #  Metaspace       used 107K, committed 320K, reserved 1114112K
  #   class space    used 7K, committed 128K, reserved 1048576K
  <parse>
   @type regexp
   expression /^(?<heap_type>[^\s]+)\s+total\s+(?<heap_total>\d+)K,\s+used\s+(?<heap_used>\d+)K\s+\[(?<heap_start>0x[0-9a-fA-F]+),\s+(?<heap_end>0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)\)$/
   types heap_total:integer, heap_used:integer
   keys heap_total, heap_used
  </parse>
</match>

But the output of fluentd traces shows me the following error:
2024-05-16 16:31:14 +0200 [error]: fluent/log.rb:404:error: config error file="test.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="'keys' parameter is required"

